# Webix: resizing column after dynamic load

Tags: javascript, webix

When I resize the Webix treetable column, after clicking on plus button, the ajax request for more data is resizing tables columns to default. How could I stop it?

Below you could see the "problem".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using `fillspace:true` for the first column, just remove it and resize will work correctly.

It is known issue for the Webix 3.x, which will be fixed in one of the next builds

Comment: Thank you! You were precise!